# Salesforce Test accesses some org records

Tags: unit-test

I'm bit new to SF.

I have problem with one of the tests. Basically I create an empty test and check if records are empty. But whatever I do, ContentNote records are not 0. When debugging, I saw that those two ContentNote records are from my development org.
My question is that why are they accessible in my test, even though I'm not using SeeAllData=true.

Assertion error I'm getting:
System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: 0, Actual: 2

Here is my sample test:

```
@IsTest
private class SomeServiceTest {
    @TestSetup
    private static void createData() {

  }

private static testMethod void testSomething() {
        System.assertEquals(0, [select Id from ContentNote].size());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you check what are the ID and other fields of that note?

Comment: ContentNote:{Id=0696E000000MmiyQAC, IsDeleted=false, OwnerId=0056E000003QFfiQAG, Title=Awersome Title, TextPreview=hello, LatestPublishedVersionId=0686E000000MtjNQAS, Content=Blob[5]}, ContentNote:{Id=0696E000000Mn5xQAC, IsDeleted=false, OwnerId=0056E000003QFfiQAG, Title=Test, LatestPublishedVersionId=0686E000000Mu6HQAS, Content=Blob[7]}

By Title-s I can see that they are my created ContentNotes in development org.

Comment: I asked someone who might know more. Note that the Isolation of Test Data from Organization Data in Unit Tests documentation uses "such as", suggesting the list included is not exhaustive.

Answer (score 0):

```
                                  **A possible bug**
```

explanation:-

### Isolation of Test Data from Organization Data in Unit Tests

> Starting with Apex code saved using Salesforce API version 24.0 and
>   later, test methods don’t have access by default to pre-existing data
>   in the organization, such as standard objects, custom objects, and
>   custom settings data, and can only access data that they create.
>   However, objects that are used to manage your organization or metadata
>   objects can still be accessed in your tests such as:

- User Profile
- Organization
- AsyncApexJob
- CronTrigger
- RecordType
- ApexClass
- ApexTrigger
- ApexComponent
- ApexPage

Note:-

Test code saved using Salesforce API version 23.0 or earlier continues to have access to all data in the organization and its data access is unchanged.

What I found is:-

I have checked the same with latest API Version and got the same problem. Also, ContentNote does not fall under any of the above listed. Also, ContentNote Object records are not organization metadata.

I would like to get verify this by others too.

Comment: You may like to mention your findings as a comment instead with proper links. Because as its answered right now, you are only validating OP's question but not really answering it. Answers are meant to provide a resolution to the original problem.

Comment: Thanks for your advice @JayantDas I will take care of these things in future

Comment: Yes I am seeing this also. Test Class using API version 44 - latest at the time @IsTest(SeeAllData=false) at top of class Also tried adding @IsTest(SeeAllData=false) into the method definition as well Double Whammy. In my test when I query for ContentNote I see records from the Sandbox. This is unexpected behaviour. I would expect to see none unless the test class creates them.

Answer (score 0):

It is expected that certain types of `SObject` are visible within a test. The documentation gives ten examples, but the list is not complete, nor was it meant to be. For example, it does not, for example, mention `StaticResource`, `PermissionSet`, or many others. The most likely explanation here is that `ContentNote` is one of those objects considered *to manage your organization*.